Cuál es la forma correcta de copiar un cert a una ruta en especifico usando Docker file en springboot?
Tengo un certificado ENV_cacerts.jks que se encuentra en la carpeta resources de un proyecto en Springboot, necesito copiar ese cert a la ruta opt/project/myapp, tengo el docker de la siguiente manera:
ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/jre/latest/bin
ENV FILE my-app-1.1.0.jar
ENV HOME /opt/project/my-app/



# Copy jar to home
ADD /target/$FILE $HOME

# Copy cert
ADD /target/ENV_cacerts.jks $HOME

# Switch to work dir
WORKDIR $HOME

# Port to expose
EXPOSE 8080

pero al montarlo me manda el siguiente error:

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
[ENV_cacerts.jks] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because
it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/opt/project/myapp

cual es la forma correcta de colocar en Docker que el cert se copie a esa ruta?
este es el path de donde tengo el cert

/my-app/src/main/resources/ENV_cacerts.jks

